# Looping through multiple text fields

Tags: java, loops, jframe, textfield

I'm trying to get multiple text fields' values in a `JFrame` at once, is there any way of going around at this? At the moment I'm using this code to generate the effect I want, but there must be an easier way like looping through it?

This is the code im using; it's used to get all textfields to get a total weight score.

```
weight = new int[15];
weight[0] = Integer.parseInt(tf_weight1.getText());
weight[1] = Integer.parseInt(tf_weight2.getText());
weight[2] = Integer.parseInt(tf_weight3.getText());
weight[3] = Integer.parseInt(tf_weight4.getText());
weight[4] = Integer.parseInt(tf_weight5.getText());
weight[5] = Integer.parseInt(tf_weight6.getText());
weight[6] = Integer.parseInt(tf_weight7.getText());
weight[7] = Integer.parseInt(tf_weight8.getText());
weight[8] = Integer.parseInt(tf_weight9.getText());
weight[9] = Integer.parseInt(tf_weight10.getText());
weight[10] = Integer.parseInt(tf_weight11.getText());
weight[11] = Integer.parseInt(tf_weight12.getText());
weight[12] = Integer.parseInt(tf_weight13.getText());
weight[13] = Integer.parseInt(tf_weight14.getText());
weight[14] = Integer.parseInt(tf_weight15.getText());
```

I was thinking of doing something alike the lines of;

```
   String s = "tf_weight";
   int inte = 1;
    for(int i = 0; i<14; i++)
    {
         s = s +  inte + ".getText()";
       for(int j = 0; j<1; j++)
        {
            inte++;
            criteria[i] = s.getText().replaceAll(" ", "~");
       }
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated greatly.

Comment: Get the frame in which you have all these textFields and then iterate through all the components in the same fashion as you have displayed

Comment: Java variables don't work that way. Why not instead put the JTextFields in a collection such as an `ArrayList< JTextField>` or perhaps better would be to use a JTable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That wouldn't work, because a string containing `"tf_weight4.getText()"` is not a method call.  Even to call a method reflectively on an object, you need the object in the first place.

There are a couple of ways you can do this:

- Keep a list of the text fields, and just iterate over it to invoke getText().  This is the easiest and most efficient way.
- Get the parent component that contains the text fields, iterate over its children, filter out the text fields and then invoke getText() on them.  With this approach, you would need a way of distinguishing the text fields you want from others that might also be in the component.

So, when you first construct your view, you need to store your text fields:

```
List<JTextField> weightFields = new ArrayList<>();
weightFields.add(tf_weight1);
weightFields.add(tf_weight2);
// and so on
```

And then, when you need to call getText()

```
List<Integer> weights = new ArrayList<>();
for (JTextField tf: weightFields) {
    weights.add(Integer.parseInt(tf.getText()));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So thanks! maybe this can help somebody:

```
    int num = 0;
    int aux = 0;
    int T   = 0;        

    JTextField txt[] = {jTextField1, jTextField2, jTextField3, jTextField4, jTextField5, jTextField6, jTextField7};
    for(int i = 1; i <= txt.length; i++){
        num = Integer.parseInt(txt[i-1].getText());

        T = aux + num;
        aux = T;
        this.jLabel2.setText(Integer.toString(T));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an array of the tf_weight objects and then loop over the
array and call the getText method.

Like:

```
JTextField textFields[] = {tf_weight1, ..., tf_weight2};
for (int i = 0; i < textFields.length; i++) {
  weight[i] = Integer.parseInt(textFields[i].getText());
}
```